# UWP app rectangle rotate

Tags: c#, uwp, rotatetransform

I create a Rectangle (enemy). The rectangle shot a bullet. When the bullet achieve the window edge, set bullet Visibility is Collapsed. After Rectangle rotate 90 degree, but I get an error. Why don't rotate?

I made a screenshot from this error:
[image: Picture]

**Enemy.cs**

```
public void rotateEnemy(Rectangle enemy)
{
    RotateTransform transform = new RotateTransform()
    {
        CenterX = 0.5,
        CenterY = 0.5,
        Angle = 90,
    };


    enemy.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5);
    enemy.RenderTransform = transform;

    Storyboard storyboard = new Storyboard();

    DoubleAnimation rotate = new DoubleAnimation();
    rotate.From = 0;
    rotate.To = 90;
    rotate.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
    rotate.AutoReverse = false;
    rotate.SetValue(Storyboard.TargetNameProperty, bullet.Name);

    Storyboard.SetTarget(rotate, bullet);
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(rotate, "(UIElement.RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)"));

    storyboard.Children.Add(rotate);
    storyboard.Begin();
}
```

Comment: Where is the variable bullet coming from? The error in the screenshot has to do with the SetTargetProperty string being used. That string is pretty tricky to get right. Sometimes you need the fully qualified string and sometimes you only need the property name. I'll try to dig up an example, but the bullet variable needs to be defined.

Comment: Ops... I made a mistake. I wanted write enemy variable and not bullet. Now it's work. Thank you :)